# Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'replace' on primefaces.js

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

I have a link to switch from lang 1 to lang 2 in xhtml:

```
<p:commandLink value="#{msgs['home.french']}" id="frenchLink" 
     rendered="#{mainBean.changeLanguage.getLanguage() ne 'fr'}"    
    actionListener="#{mainBean.refreshPage}" ajax="false">  
  <f:param name="selectedLanguage" value="fr"/>
</p:commandLink>

<p:commandLink value="#{msgs['home.english']}" id="englishLink" r
    endered="#{mainBean.changeLanguage.getLanguage() ne 'en'}"  actionListener="#{mainBean.refreshPage}" ajax="false">
    <f:param name="selectedLanguage" value="en"/>
</p:commandLink>
```

and  in mainBean,

```
public void refreshPage(ActionEvent event){
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(); 
        String language = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("selectedLanguage");
        changeLanguage = new ChangeLanguage();
        ChangeLanguage.setLanguage(language);
        String viewId = context.getViewRoot().getViewId(); 
        ViewHandler handler = context.getApplication().getViewHandler(); 
        UIViewRoot root = handler.createView(context, viewId); 
        root.setViewId(viewId); 
        context.setViewRoot(root);
        context.renderResponse();
}
```

Always getting **Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'replace'** on primefaces.js

These issue popup only when I switch to french and the pages having selectOneMenu, dialogs.

Any pointers on this appreciated.

App uses Jsf 2.0, Primefaces 3.5

Comment: I need to retain the view page details as well, that's why I'm using handler to set it back to context.

Comment: Mainly the problem seems to creep on primefaces js reload. Should I need to mention something explicitly in web.xml related to primefaces??

Comment: Are you manually including another copy of jQuery? If so, why exactly?

Answer (score -1):

Define the default language in yor faces-config.xml

```
 <application>
       <locale-config>
            <default-locale>en</default-locale>
       </locale-config>
 </application>
```

Recommend that your bean is `@SessionScoped`, then consider creating a bean just to control the location of your system.

In your Bean create this properties.

```
private static Map<String,Locale> countries;
    static{
        countries = new HashMap<String,Locale>();
        countries.put("fr", Locale.FRANCE);
        countries.put("en", Locale.ENGLISH);
    }
```

Add method to change language.

```
public void changeLanguage(){
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(); 
        String language = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("selectedLanguage");
        context.getViewRoot().setLocale(countries.get(language));
}
```

In your view (xhtml):

```
<p:commandLink value="#{msgs['home.french']}" id="frenchLink" 
    rendered="#{mainBean.changeLanguage.getLanguage() ne 'fr'}"    
    actionListener="#{mainBean.changeLanguage}" ajax="false" 
    oncomplete="javascript:location.reload(true)">  
  <f:param name="selectedLanguage" value="fr"/>
</p:commandLink>

<p:commandLink value="#{msgs['home.english']}" id="englishLink"
    rendered="#{mainBean.changeLanguage.getLanguage() ne 'en'}"  actionListener="#{mainBean.changeLanguage}" ajax="false" 
    oncomplete="javascript:location.reload(true)">
    <f:param name="selectedLanguage" value="en"/>
</p:commandLink>
```

Comment: Does not explain, but it is a better solution that works correctly than the form proposed.